# StopIteration exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyperclip

function

```
def _copying(self):
    result = self.result.toPlainText().strip().split('\n')
    to_copy = '\n'.join(result)

    pyperclip.copy(to_copy)
```

in the `MainWindow()` of my PyQt5 project raises an exception "StopIteration" in contextlib.py `_GeneratorContextManager()`, `line 119 'next(self.gen)'`.
`result` is a `ui.TextEdit` object. Could u please tell me what does it mean? 
Google says i should wrap my func into with-construction, but i don't really inderstand how, and don't sure it's a good idea.

Debugger says:

```
__exception__ = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: (<class 'StopIteration'>, StopIteration(), <traceback object at 0x045DA918>)
 0 = {type} <class 'StopIteration'>
  args = {getset_descriptor} <attribute 'args' of 'BaseException' objects>
  value = {member_descriptor} <member 'value' of 'StopIteration' objects>
 1 = {StopIteration} 
  args = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ()
  value = {NoneType} None
 2 = {traceback} <traceback object at 0x045DA918>
  tb_frame = {frame} __exit__ [contextlib.py:119]  id:54111736
  tb_lasti = {int} 16
  tb_lineno = {int} 119
  tb_next = {NoneType} None
 __len__ = {int} 3
```

Console says nothing. But the project is crashing.

Comment: Show us a full traceback.

Comment: @AlexHall Updated

Comment: That's not a traceback. A traceback is the thing from "Traceback (most recent call last):" up to "WhateverError: stuff broke because reasons" that gets printed when an exception isn't handled. You probably can't show us one, because this exception is normal and gets handled.

Comment: What do you mean by crashing? It just stops abruptly with no exception? Do you only see the StopIteration in the debugger?

Comment: @AlexHall Yes, it's what i mean by crashing. And yes, i only see this exception in the debugger. Console isn't show any problems.

Comment: @AlexHall well. The problem is solved by herself. Obviously there's another reason of crashes. Could it be something about memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That StopIteration is completely normal and expected. It's part of the normal operation of `contextlib.contextmanager`. It's supposed to happen, and it's caught and handled immediately; if it *doesn't* happen, there's a problem.

I don't know how you've even ended up at the point where you're looking at this exception, considering how it never escapes the `contextlib` internals, but if you're blaming it for your code's problems, you're blaming the wrong thing.

Comment: Oh wow. Now it works without any problems. I'll will reproduce the bug, but i still don'h have any ideas about the reason of crashes. Could it be something about memory?